# For loop not executing

Tags: python, directory, filepath

I need to open the root folder named: 'data' and then to go get the list of folders in that folder and later to take the path of each and to execute some code that checks if inside those folders is a 'docx' file.

If a execute only this:

```
rootDir = 'data'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName == 'data':
        pass
    else:
        print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
```

As result I get a list of all folders

```
Found directory: data/2014 09 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2014 11 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2014 03 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2015 04 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2015 03 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2015 08 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2014 10 Daily Reports 
Found directory: data/2015 07 Daily Reports 
.....
```

But if I include this:

```
rootDir = 'data'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName == 'data':
        pass
    else:
        dirpath = os.path.abspath(dirName)
        for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
            for f in filenames:
                os.chdir(dirpath)
                fn = f.replace('\xc3\xab','e')
                os.rename(f, f.replace('\xc3\xab','e'))
                if 'docx' in f:
                    print 'docx files are found inside this folder'
                else:
                    pass 
        print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
```

if a execute this,the result is only this:

```
Found directory: data/2014 09 Daily Reports
```

Why is the for loop not executing? Any help?

Comment: I don't understand something : `os.walk` automatically go through all files or directorys in the `rootDir`. ALL files, so also files in sub-directories. Why do you want to run a walk in a walk ?

Comment: @FunkySayu Maybe OP needs to learn how to `walk` before they run.

Comment: Looks like you changed directory with `os.chdir()`, so you are no longer where you thought you were.

Answer (score 2):

that's happening because you're executing `os.chdir` inside the loop.

the `os.walk` won't find the "data" directory inside the directory that it was changed to in the previous execution of the loop, you need either change `rootDir` to provide the **"full/path/to/data"** directory or try to execute `os.chdir("..")` inside the loop to go back the previous directory.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Is any possibility that  in the end after else condition to  change directory back to my original working directory?

Comment: yeah I guess executing `os.chdir(dirpath)` and `os.chdir("..")` outside the second nested loop should do the job. put them before and after it respectively.